# Letsencrypt autorenewal not working

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I ran `certbot renew` on my domains, but the expiration hasn't updated. How can I tell what I did wrong?

Exact steps:

```bash
$ sudo certbot renew --force-renewal
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Processing
/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/eu-central-1.workbook.[domain].conf
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Renewing an existing certificate for us-east-1.workbook.[domain] and 4 more domains
Reloading nginx server after certificate renewal

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/us-east-1.workbook.[domain].conf
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Renewing an existing certificate for us-east-1.workbook.[domain]
Reloading nginx server after certificate renewal

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Congratulations, all renewals succeeded: 
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/eu-central-1.workbook.[domain]/fullchain.pem (success)
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/us-east-1.workbook.[domain]/fullchain.pem (success)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

Comment: Start by examining the certificates on a disk and see if they have the updated expiration date you expect. Then check and make sure your nginx configuration is referencing the correct path(s), and confirm that nginx actually restarted (and if not, restart it).